# Can't connect to postgresql using sqlworkbench/j

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, sql-workbench-j

I am trying to create a profile on SQLWorkbench/J to access a postgresql server on a virtual machine running ubuntu.

I install the appropriate jdbc driver and set the URL:
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/(dbname)

I get the message: `Password authentication failed for user: (user)`

It variously asks or assumes (presumably) the password but gives the same result in any case.

This is from the log:

```
2018-10-16 12:09:07 EDT FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "(user)"
2018-10-16 12:09:07 EDT DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 92: "host    all             all            
127.0.0.1/32            md5"
```

I can make this work by going into pg_hba.conf and changing `md5` to `trust` on line 92 and this will serve for development but would be wholly inappropriate if I move the server to production. I have also tried changing the 'md5' to 'password', also inappropriate but doesn't work.

I get into the server using psql without problems either using the simple command `psql` or `psql -U (user) -W` for my user but for other users the password that works for `su (user)` doesn't work with `psql -U (user) -W`. All these users are associated with UNIX accounts.

Is there any way to know what password to use or is there a special set of users that can be accessed in this way? Or is there a special way to set up a user for access by something other than psql? I simply want to be connected via appropriate authorization.

Comment: "*Password authentication failed for user*" means you supplied the wrong password. If you don't know the password, you need to log in as the superuser `postgres` and change the password for the user you use from within SQL Workbench

Comment: Read the text. Why does it work with psql but not with SQL Workbench? Does psql require a different password?